# Converting String of a given alphabet to an integer

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a working function that converts an integer to a string of length k over a given alphabet A

```
def ToString(x, k, A):
    """
    Args:
       x (int):     Integer x ∈ N
       k (int)      String length k >= log_N (x)
       A (list)     Alphabet A = {c_1, ..., c_N}
    """

    S = ""
    N = len(A)

    for i in reversed(range(0, k)):
        s_k = A[x % N]
        x = x // N
        S += s_k

    return S
```

Test:

```
  A = ['0', '1']  # Alphabet
  k = 8           # length
  x = 5           # the number to convert
  s = ToString(x, k, A) # s = '10100000'
```

So now I basically need the exact inverse of this function, so I can convert the string '10100000' and the given alphabet back to 5

```
def ToInteger(S, A):
    """    
    Args:
       S (str):     String
       A (list):    Alphabet

    Returns:
       int:         Integer
    """
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(S)):
        x = len(A) * x + len(A)-1-A.index(S[i])
    return x
```

Unfortunately, this returns garbage:

```
i = StringToInteger('10100000',['0','1']) # = 95
```

This is how the algorithm specification looks like:
[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: the problem in your function is that you should use instead of `x = len(A) * x + len(A)-1-A.index(S[i])` this `x = len(A) * x + A.index(S[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use in you first function, `S = s_k + S` instead of `S += s_k`
Then use this function:

```
def toInteger(S, A):
   x = 0
   for i in range(len(S)):
     x += (len(A) ** (len(S) - 1 - i)) * (A.index(S[i]))
   return x
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine! Thank you